# How to timeout in mod_perl?

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout, mod-perl

I'm looking for a server-wide setting for timeout with mod_perl scripts under Apache 2.2, similar to `max_execution_time` in php.

[Timeout can be done with `$SIG{ALRM}`](http://modperlbook.org/html/6-10-Handling-Server-Timeout-Cases-and-Working-with-SIG-AL.html) but it requires modification to every perl script and is incompatible with with `sleep()`.

Apache has a [`TimeOut` configuration directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout), however it has no effect on mod_perl. With `TimeOut 5`, timeout does not occur for a test script that sleeps for 10 seconds before printing anything.

The `Apache2::ServerRec` module has a `timeout()` method, but it simply gets/sets the value of Apache's `TimeOut` variable, and therefore has no effect on mod_perl as well.

How can it be done? If it cannot be done, what is the best practice for timeout in mod_perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_perl` does not, unfortunately, have a way of doing this.  What *does* have a way of implementing timeouts its `mod_fcgid` (via the [FcgidBusyTimeout directive](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidbusytimeout)).  This shouldn't require any significant modifications to your script, unless its making use of `mod_perl` specific functionality.

A good comparison between `mod_perl` and `mod_fcgid` is [available on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382798/mod-perl-vs-mod-fastcgi), but if implementing universal timeouts is your requirement, `mod_fcgid` sounds like its the only way to go.